# Vertex Shader and Fragment Shader(s) failed to compile before gllinkProgram() was called,

Tags: c++, opengl

Both the vertex shader and fragment shader are small flies ( files ) for a small red box to appear on a blue background.

Here they are:

1st one is colorShading.vert

```
#version 130
in vec2 vertexPosition;
void main(){
gl_Positiion.xy = vertexPosition;
gl_Positiion.z = 0;
gl_Positiion.w = 1;
}
```

2nd One is colorShading.frag

```
#version 130
out vec3 color;
void main(){
color vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

and Here is the error:

```
Vertex and Fragment shader(s) were not successfully compiled 
before glLinkProgram() was called.  Link failed.
Shaders failed to link!
Enter any key to quit...
```

I used a console to output it using

```
std::vector<GLchar> errorLog(maxLength);
glGetProgramInfoLog(_programID, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorLog[0]);
std::printf("%s\n", &(errorLog[0]));
fatalError("Shaders failed to link!");`
```

The function I used to compile the Shaders is below

and I pass the filepath and shaderID to the function, rather than copying and pasting, Convenient right?

```
    void GLSLProgram::compileShader(const std::string& filePath, GLuint& id)
{
    std::ifstream shaderFile(filePath);
    if (shaderFile.fail()) {
        perror(filePath.c_str());
        fatalError("Failed to Open  " + filePath);
    }
    std::string fileContents = "";
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(shaderFile, line)) {
        fileContents += line + "\n";
    }
    shaderFile.close();
    const char* contentsPtr = fileContents.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &contentsPtr, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);
    GLint success = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (success = GL_FALSE) {
        GLint maxLength = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);
        //The maxLength include the NULL character
        std::vector<char> errorLog(maxLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorLog[0]);
        //Exit with failure
        glDeleteShader(id);
        std::printf("%s\n", &(errorLog[0]));
        fatalError(" Shader " +filePath +" failed to compile!");
        return;
    }
 }
```

How do I go about this error I am getting?

Comment: What error *are* you getting?

Comment: The Vertex shader and Fragment shader are not being compiled

Comment: `success = GL_FALSE` Pay attention to your compiler's warnings.

Comment: I do not quite understand

Comment: your shaders are invalid, as is your error checking code

Comment: Could you help me get it correct, I just recently started doing this work, reading some documentations and watching some videos  Here is the video link where I did exactly what the person tells to and at the end of the video he gets his program correct  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLUtSE2osfI&list=PLSPw4ASQYyymu3PfG9gxywSPghnSMiOAW&index=10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code sample misspells `gl_Position` as `gl_Positiion`.

Comment: Yeah got everything working, but still I am unable to get a red color in the box

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two problems in your code:

**Compilation Code**

The `if` statement that checks for successful compilation contains an assignment, not a comparison:

```
if (success = GL_FALSE) {
```

what you actually need is (not the two equal signs):

```
if (success == GL_FALSE) {
```

Every compiler I know would at least give a warning on this.

**Shader**

In the fragment shader, there is also a = sign missing:

```
color vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

This is not valid glsl code. Most probably you wanted to assign this color, thus the code should be

```
color = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```